# Will my kitten have short hair or long hair

Tags: cats

Meet Fairyfloss. He is 7 weeks old, he has hair on his belly and has a thick coat on his back. However he doesn’t have long ear tufts or fur between his paws. Any guesses? His fur on his neck seems also not too short so I’m confused... any suggestions or ideas as to what he will be? His tail isn’t very fluffy but he looks very in the middle.[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't really answerable for sure, but his coat looks more like my longhair cat's when she was a kitten, my guess is medium/long.